# Load data from sqlite to a custom listview but nullpointer exception error occurs

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have created an activity for loading data into a custom listview with two textboxes. But the app closes unexpectedly with

> unable to start activity componentinfo java.lang.nullpointerexception error.

My Auto Java is

```
public class Auto extends ListActivity {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "koottam.sqlite3";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "auto";
    private static final String FIELD_ID = "SNo";
    private static final String FIELD_NAME = "Name";
    private static final String FIELD_NUM = "Number";

    SqlHandler sqlHandler;

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> friends;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto);
        // get action bar   
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Enabling Up / Back navigation
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
       // DBAdapter dbOpenHelper = new DBAdapter(this, DB_NAME);
        //database = dbOpenHelper.openDataBase();
        showlist();
       // fillList();
        //setUpList();      
    }

    /*
    private void setUpList() {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, friends));
        listView = getListView();
        TextView phone=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.auto_tv1);


        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position,long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            ((TextView) view).getText().toString(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                
            }
        });
    }

    private void fillList() {
        friends = new ArrayList<String>();
        Cursor friendCursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,
                                             new String[] 
                                             {FIELD_ID, FIELD_NAME,FIELD_NUM},
                                             null, null, null, null
                                             , FIELD_NAME);
        friendCursor.moveToFirst();
        if(!friendCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            do {
                String name = friendCursor.getString(1);
                friends.add(name);
            } while (friendCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        friendCursor.close();
    }

    */
    private void showlist() {

        ArrayList<listRowAuto> contactList = new ArrayList<listRowAuto>();
        contactList.clear();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM auto ";
        Cursor c1 = sqlHandler.selectQuery(query);
        if (c1 != null && c1.getCount() != 0) {
            if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    listRowAuto contactListItems = new listRowAuto();


                    contactListItems.setName(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("name")));
                    contactListItems.setPhone(c1.getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex("phone")));
                    contactList.add(contactListItems);

                } while (c1.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        c1.close();

        listAdapterAuto contactListAdapter = new listAdapterAuto(
                Auto.this, contactList);
        listView.setAdapter(contactListAdapter);

    }}
```

My ListAdapter Class

```
public class listAdapterAuto extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;
    ArrayList<listRowAuto> autoList;

    public listAdapterAuto(Context context, ArrayList<listRowAuto> list) {

        this.context = context;
        autoList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return autoList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return autoList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
        listRowAuto autoListItems = autoList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_auto, null);

        }

        TextView tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.auto_tv1);
        tvName.setText(autoListItems.getName());
        TextView tvPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.auto_tv2);
        tvPhone.setText(autoListItems.getPhone());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I don't know where I am getting this error.
Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code there is no initialization before calling this line-

```
sqlHandler.selectQuery(query);
```

add the below code in your  oncreate

```
sqlHandler=new SqlHandler(getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: @SanjuPazhankannur initialization of sqlHandler

Comment: first of all what is sqlHandler?? .. if you have the class file in your project??

Comment: public SqlHandler(Context context) {

  dbHelper = new SqlDbHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,
    DATABASE_VERSION);
  sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
 }
public Cursor selectQuery(String query) {
  Cursor c1 = null;
  try {

   if (sqlDatabase.isOpen()) {
    sqlDatabase.close();

   }
   sqlDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   c1 = sqlDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);

  } catch (Exception e) {

   System.out.println("DATABASE ERROR " + e);

  }
  return c1;

 }

}

Comment: my logcat shows this 
12-26 06:34:53.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1131): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-26 06:34:53.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
12-26 06:34:53.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
12-26 06:34:53.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
12-26 06:34:53.757: E/AndroidRuntime(1131):

Comment: can anyone help me with this?? : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo : Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: I have used the cursor adapter but why does this error?